# authentication redirect signin and log out uri

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, webapi

I've only used Identity Server to implement security so far. When I tried to use a different one, I've been asked to provide a callback url, which represents in a way the redirect uri, where the identity provider will redirect after completing authentication.

And I never wondered about this until I actually have been asked to provide that callback url. Because in Identity Server, I never configured any redirect uri such as [www.someWebsite.com/signin-oidc](http://www.someWebsite.com/signin-oidc), but still I wrote it because ... that's how everyone does it. Later on, after some digging up on OIDC, it turns out it was the convention and was handled by the identity provider (Identity Server) middleware itself.

Which brought this question up: if I had to provide some url callback, should I create a web api that will handle the operation? Like the middleware does with /signin-oidc endpoint. (unless it will always be handled by the identity provider middleware and this case, I just need to provide web app host like [www.someWebSite.com](http://www.someWebSite.com))

If so ... i don't even know where to start. Like what it should do eventually? and what happens next.

Thank you for your time

Comment: checkout this [article](https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/asp-net-core-google-authentication-4c0aa8feebbc)

Comment: One thing for sure: we don't create an endpoint at the hostUri/signin-idp. In the article, it made wonder even more :) I don't know what he does with the redirect uri in his asp.net core project (the web app which asks the user to log in via google). The more I learn about this, the more I feel I'm far from being done. Thanks for the article

Comment: its a built in api when you install the third party authentication package (google auth,...) it comes to you code

Comment: OK ok ok, I got you. In the article, I think he was doing it all from scratch, while that logic of retrieving the redirect uri for example could be provided by the 3rd party library. I didn't make the connection in the first place. Thanks for pointing it out.